# WPF - Notify Icon

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, icons

I'm trying to implement an `Notify Icon` in my app. I've tried this: http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon but for some reason didn't work. I copied & paste the example code and even create a new project, just for practice purpose and still nothing.

Sadly I have lose a lot of hours searching for other solutions but with no luck.

How do you implement `Notify Icons` or similar in your `WPF applications`?

**Code tried XAML**

```
xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"

<tb:TaskbarIcon x:Name="MyNotifyIcon" IconSource="/Icons/Error.ico" ToolTipText="hello world" />
```

The error is: Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll

Best regards,

Comment: I've been using the lib you mention for years, and it works fine (mostly). You can use it as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf/) if it makes things easier.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I've tried just know and for some reason it shows an error. I will layout the error here for you..See EDIT in the main post

Comment: XamlParseException doesn't give enough information, you need to look at the InnerException

Comment: It says it can't find the resource but its strange because the resource is there. In the right folder -.-' **/Resources/Images/logosmall.ico**   ... And from the properties of the image: `WpfWHERE\Resources\Images`

Comment: Make sure the image has "Resource" as its build action

Comment: @ThomasLevesque  Sorry I didn't understand what you mean :S

Comment: When you select the image file in the Solution Explorer, right click, Properties, make sure the "Build action" property is set to "Resource"

Comment: Thomas it worked. Thank you very much